# Unused dependencies Shows in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies

I'm developing flutter application and I using below dependencies for my project.

- webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
- connectivity_plus: ^2.2.0
- html: ^0.15.0
- sn_progress_dialog: ^1.0.3
- http: ^0.13.4
- pin_code_fields: ^7.3.0
- flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
- url_launcher: ^6.0.20
- datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
- extended_masked_text: ^2.3.1
- image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
- timelines: ^0.1.0
- carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
- page_transition: ^2.0.5
- provider: ^6.0.2
- native_updater: ^0.1.1
- flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
- dropdown_search: ^2.0.1
- flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
- expandable: ^5.0.1
- crypto: ^3.0.1
- device_info_plus: ^3.2.1
- dart_ipify: ^1.1.1
- qr_code_scanner: ^0.6.1
- flutter_jailbreak_detection: ^1.8.0
- flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
- firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
- firebase_core: ^1.12.0
- cloud_firestore: ^3.1.8
- flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
- google_directions_api: ^0.9.0
- geolocator: ^8.2.0
- geocoding: ^2.0.2
- google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
- location: ^4.3.0
- flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
- permission_handler: ^9.2.0

But in my android folder shows unused dependencies . Anyone can explain this and how to remove this from project ?
[image]
Ex:package_info_plus

Comment: Those are library packages and you can't remove them if you want to use them and if you don't want to use them then just remove them from pubspec.yaml and the respective folders will be removed when you run command 'pub get'.

Comment: alredey follow those steps buts still package info shows inside the android folder

Comment: run flutter clean then run flutter pub get

Comment: Try removing unused folder manually once and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I am giving the correct answer but, this may be because each flutter package/plugin may depend on others. If you see the [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) you will see its dependencies. See the below image.

[image]